# What is the matter with my apache?

Tags: apache-httpd, php

Today my `apache2` suddenly didn't run.

```
cat /var/www/html/info.php
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

No output, no error info at all, no result when to input `http://127.0.0.1/info.php` in Firefox.
[image]

```
cat  /var/log/apache2/error.log
Nothing!!
```

What is the matter with my `apache2`?

```
 service apache2 restart
```

And then to input `http://127.0.0.1/info.php` in Firefox,

```
cat  /var/log/apache2/error.log

[Fri Sep 18 16:06:54.065576 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16124:tid 139930869675904] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Sep 18 16:06:55.182391 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 20296:tid 139659549255552] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 18 16:06:55.182555 2015] [core:notice] [pid 20296:tid 139659549255552] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

No output,no error info ,no result in the Firefox as before.
```

Comment: We are going to need way more info. Does a static page work?

Comment: A ststic html page can be displayed normally.

Comment: `php  /var/www/html/info.php ` can work in the terminal .

Comment: Have you tried restarting `apache`, then trying again?

Comment: It is no use to restart it.

Comment: can you check if php is installed in your server ?

Comment: Did you check that the request appears in your access_log? (might be cached/redirected)